# rspec ruby on rails newbie question about controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

im new to RoR or rspec and trying to learn it.First of all i cant find tutorials for newbies, just advanced ones, becouse i want to learn RoR and at the same time learn to test.
Im writing test for simple CRUD controllers, but i have no idea how to test for example if params passed to my create action, also if it was saved.

```
def create
    @item = TextItem.new(params[:item])

    if @item.save
       redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
       render('new')
      end
  end
```

Comment: I find RoR tutorial by Michael Hartl as a great resource for learning RoR and rspec. [link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to become familiar with rails and ruby and only then dive into tdd/bdd with test/unit or minitest or rspec, cucumber or a lot of other testing techniques.

I recommend you to buy a book/ebook to start, for example this one [Agile rails development with rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails), ebook only $24. You will save a lot of time.

Sometimes Rspec is a little bit tricky/magical and without base knowledge of rails/ruby it can be difficult to start using.

I don't suggest you to study rails and rspec in one attempt.

BTW specs for this action can be like that:

```
  describe "POST create" do
    let(:item) { mock_model(TextItem) }

    before(:each) do
      TextItem.stub(:new).and_return(item)
    end

    it "saves the item" do
      item.should_receive(:save)
      post :create
    end

    context "when the item saves successfully" do
      before(:each) do
        item.stub(:save).and_return(true)
      end

      it "redirects to the items index" do
        post :create
        response.should redirect_to(:action => "index")
      end
    end

    context "when the item fails to save" do
      before(:each) do
        item.stub(:save).and_return(false)
        item.stub_chain(:errors, :empty?).and_return(false)
      end

      it "renders the new template" do
        post :create
        response.should render_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end
```